# slide view pager image view

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, image-gallery

Please help. I have 3 imageview getresources Intent.putExtra listview from database. I want imageview click open new activity and then swipe to move next image. what should i do? thank for advance

[second_activity ImageView](http://www.image-share.com/upload/2341/140.jpg)

```
// Declare Variables
String title;
String firstimages, secondimages, thirdimages;
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page_single_itemview);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Get the result of image
    firstimages = i.getStringExtra("first_image");
     secondimages = i.getStringExtra("second_image"); 
      thirdimages = i.getStringExtra("third_image");

    // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
    TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
    ImageView imgImageone = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_single_one);
     ImageView imgImagetwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_single_two);
      ImageView imgImagethree = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_single_three);

    txttitle.setText(title);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(firstimages, imgImageone);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(secondimages, imgImagetwo);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(thirdimages, imgImagethree);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check out [android-code-snippet-listening-swipe](http://droidcoder.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-code-snippet-listening-swipe.html) blogpost for swipe event. You can add swipe event for your whole activity or for any view you want to. Based on your swipe event change the image/imageview.